# Stack trace debugging from crash count report - Microsoft.Phone.Controls.NativeMethods.ValidateHResult

Tags: windows-phone-7, exception, stack-trace, crash-reports

Hopefully you can help me with analysing of a specific exception present in the crash count report from Windows Phone store.

The following exception does not cause app crash, however since it happens a lot (the report says +1200 for the last month) it affects the Windows Store app rating which affects the app downloads.
The app is available on the store both as Free (with ads) and Paid version (without ads). Since this exception is present only in the free version I suspect that the reason for it are the ads (the Paid verison is copy of the Free one only without ads). For showing the ads I use the AdRotator control (version 1).

Below you may find more details about the exception.

**Problem function:** Unknown

**Exception type:** SystemException

**OS version:** 7.1

**Stack trace:**

"Frame    Image             Function                                                                                       Offset
0        coredll.dll                                                                                                      256911
1        mscoree3_7.dll                                                                                                   436172
2        mscoree3_7.dll                                                                                                   383681
3        mscoree3_7.dll                                                                                                   540620
4                          TransitionStub                                                                                 0
5                          Microsoft.Phone.Controls.NativeMethods.ValidateHResult                                         236
6                          Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowserInterop.InvokeScript                                        128
7                          Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowser.InvokeScript                                               84
8                          .__c__DisplayClass36._RunScripts_b__34                                                         228
9        mscoree3_7.dll                                                                                                   428848
10       mscoree3_7.dll                                                                                                   222523
11       mscoree3_7.dll                                                                                                   221143
12                         System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke                                             112
13                         System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke                                             1556
14                         System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke                                                            104
15                         System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne                                                               564
16                         System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl                                                     84
17                         System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke                                            80
18                         System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch                                                   404
19                         System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke                                                   56"

Any help is more than welcomed.